# I've given Gwei less than 0.1 for a transaction, and it's been an hour, and it is not showing up in etherscan!

Tags: solidity, transactions, ether, etherscan, out-of-gas

I know I pretty much messed up with Gwei, I've given it < 0.1. My doubt is if the transaction gets failed will the funds get back to my wallet or lost forever and how much time will it take for the transaction to get rejected? Do I have to wait for several days?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which wallet you used if its Metamask you can replace the transaction with another that pays a higher gas price.

And waiting for several days does not mean the transaction will get mined for it to be rejected. The best approach is to replace the transaction with another transaction with a higher gas price.

If the wallet you used is Metamask you can find instructions [here](https://medium.com/metamask/regarding-pending-transactions-4ec0ec23140d) else try reaching out to the customer support of the wallet used.